# Shopware API call on Customer Resource responds with "Resource not found"

Tags: php, shopware

I tried to call the Customers Resource on my Shopware server running in a local VM, but all I get is a 404 'Resource not found' response.

When I echo the URL that the REST client uses and call it manually from my Browser it works just fine and I get the proper customers JSON.

The REST client I use is the one from the shopware AI tutorial with no changes:
https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/#using-the-rest-api-in-your-own-application

The client seems to be alright, as I can use it to create customers.

Nevertheless this code does not work:

```php
$client = new ApiClient($CONF_SW_RESTServerDomain, $CONF_SW_username, $CONF_SW_APIKey);
$customers = $client->get('customers');
if (empty($customers)) { throw new Exception("error, failed to get customers."); }
```

I expect to get a result like that

```php
$customers = json_decode({"data":[{"number":"20003","id":1,"chang...bleOptinConfirmDate":null}],"total":1,"success":true}, true);
```

but all I get is the exception line below being triggered.

I am puzzled, any ideas?

Comment: Maybe is the network config on your VM , are you using Windows? or linux? $CONF_SW_RESTServerDomain is this pointing to localhost?? i suspect the request is going from inside de VM , can have different address between host and VM ..

Comment: @JoaquinJavi thanks for the quick response. You helped me to find the issue: $CONF_SW_RESTServerDomain = "192.168.178.30/api" but needs to have a  "http://". Now it works... :)

Comment: HTTP: 201
Success
;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was

```
$CONF_SW_RESTServerDomain = "192.168.178.30/api";
```

needs to be

```
$CONF_SW_RESTServerDomain = "http://192.168.178.30/api";
```

works fine now :)